# Search folder name in whole disk/subfolders via FINDSTR by one line cmd?

Tags: windows, search, cmd, grep, findstr

I need to find just a folder **wwwroot** in whole **disk F** , and not files. Only folder. Is that possible by one line in cmd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `dir /?` for help.

```
Dir f:\wwwroot /ad /s
```

Comment: If you open a Command Prompt window, type `dir /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, you should see all of the usage information for the command. Within it, you should note that you can use the `/B` option to reduce the output to just the fully qualified file name. Additionally you may find that including filters like `-R`, `-H`, -`S` and `-L` may speed up the results too, by ignoring read only, hidden, and system files as well as directory junctions. Example: `Dir F:\wwwroot /A:D-H-L-R-S /B /S`. Even if those `/A` options don't speed it up for you, they're more likely to reduce unwanted matches.